# Prevent height of the container to grow as we add records

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to display a list of records in a page. The issue that i am currently facing is, as i add new records to the list the page size increases and it adds a scrollbar. But i dont want the page to show results in the scrollbar, instead i want the scrollbar inside the grid table and fix the height of the whole container to the height of the div.

I do not want to fix the height of the div as it had few dependencies. I want to make the table of records not to expand as we add contents. I was able to achieve this by fixing the height by calculating vh and other containers on the page and setting the height of table container to 100%. But i want it to a way where we can only update the css without calculation. Like removing flex that allows it to grow etc

The table has 3 divs. A header for the table, table contents and footer. I want the scrollbar inside the header and footer , not on the web page that increases the height of the page as we add records

[Expected Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JFgm.png)

[Current Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnXSw.png)

I tried overflow-y to be scroll on the table div but of no luck.
Tried height 100%, flex-grow - 0.

Can someone point out to a simple css fix that might end up fixing this?

Comment: pls add you code as a snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use css grid. Example:

```
<style>
      .layout {
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
      }
      .header {
        background: #ccc;
      }
      .content {
        overflow: auto;
      }
      .footer {
        background: #ddd;
      }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="layout">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="content">Content</div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```